# What does the term "carebear" mean in Eve Online?

Tags: terminology, eve-online

I've recently re-activated my account. I've seen this term used in the online chat and wondered what it means.

Comment: its not only used in EVE Online ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A "Carebear" is a derogatory term used for characters who stay mostly in Concord (police) controlled space and never ventures into unsecured "0.0" space.

Basically synonymous to cowards.

Comment: I think anyone whose been on the end of the famous http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Care_Bears#Care_Bear_Stare_and_Cousin_Call would disagree with the term cowards :) but I see your point so answer accepted, cheers!

Comment: I don't agree with carebears not venturing into 0.0 space. They often go into null sec when it's financially profitable. They just avoid any kind of pvp. 0.0 offers lot's of PVE opportunities.

Comment: No, carebears are the kind of people that avoid any kind of danger.

Comment: I wouldn't use the synonym of "coward".

Comment: There are plenty of carebears in nullsec, they just do PvE stuff.  Carebear is just someone who doesn't do much, if any, PvP.  Conversely, one doesn't have to go all the way out to nullsec to pirate or anti-pirate--oh the joys of lowsec

Comment: "Carebear" just means "They're not playing this game the way I think they should be playing it, so I'll make derogatory aspersions to their courage and/or skill and/or emotional maturity because that always convinces people that my way of playing is more fun."

Comment: @Shadur: Sad, but oh-so-true.

Comment: We liked our carebears; they mined for us. We blew up other people's.

Answer (score 54):

This term spans wider than Eve.  [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Care%20Bear) defines "care bear":

> 1. Lightly derogatory term for an MMO player who avoids PVP combat, heavily preferring cooperative or solo PVE combat, chatting, or developing tradeskills/running quests. Depending on the game and the individual, this PVP avoidance can show up in several ways: by playing on strict non-PVP servers; by avoiding PVP areas or declining duels; or, by avoiding or condemning PVP players.

Comment: If you look up "carebear" (merge the words together) it shows both this general definition and the Eve-specific one.

Answer (score 14):

A carebear is someone who avoids pvp. Quite frankly, I'm a carebear, but I live in nullsec areas, I just run away and hide, and only go where no one else is.